# Chicago Fed National Activity Index: underlying data download

Tags: data-request

Is there quick way to download the 85 time series (already transformed, i.e., seasonally adjusted and stationarized, if necessary) that are used to construct the Chicago Fed National Activity Index (CFNAI)?

https://www.chicagofed.org/publications/cfnai/index

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not related to economics. It is about how to collect some data from a website.

Comment: I may be missing something then: what website do you suggest to download that data from? Because I just don't know where to find it!

Comment: It is a safe bet that they are either available at FRED (St. Louis Fed) as raw series, or are data you need to pay for access (in which case there’s no legitimate free source).

Answer (score 1):

Friend.   Yes there is.   You can use the St. Louis Federal Reserve Economic Data download website (FRED)     https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/CFNAI

Not sure about seasonal adjustment.  For seasonal adjustment you may need a statistical computing software to do that and you would have to choice your parameters.